# AngularJS bootstrap.ui modal not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to display a modal dialog using AngularJS bootstrap.ui.  When I do a $modal.open(...) the screen grays out and the html from my templateUrl get called from the server, but no modal displays.  When I click on the gray area, the modal "closes", that is the gray area goes away and the screen looks normal again.  I cannot figure out why I don't see any modal screen.

I am trying to follow this tutorial:
[Angular directives](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

I am using Visual Studio 2013, MVC 5, AngularJS 1.2.2.

I am using bootstrap.css that comes with the VS project.  It has the modal classes in it.  I am getting no error reported from the Javascript console.  My app is defined as follows:

```
var blogApp = angular.module('blogApp', ['ngResource', 'ngSanitize', 'ui.bootstrap']) ...

blogApp.controller('blogController',
function blogController($scope, $modal, $log, blogData, userData) {

    ...

    $scope.showPrivacy = function() {
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: '/Privacy',
            controller: 'PrivacyInstanceController'
        });
        return false;
    };
});


var PrivacyInstanceController = function($scope, $modalInstance) {
    $scope.close = function() {
        $modalInstance.close();
    };
}
```

And my markup is:

```
<div ng-controller="blogController">
        <a ng-click="showPrivacy()">Privacy Policy</a>
    </div>
```

Any idea why my screen is graying out, the /Privacy resource is getting loaded and the screen returns to normal when the gray is clicked, but no modal appears?

Comment: I suspect that you are using Bootstrap3 CSS and the current release version is only compatible with Bootstrap 2.3. If you want to use this library with Bootstrap3 you need to build the bootstrap3 branch on your side (until it is officially released and supported).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Have exactly the same symptoms while ago. Do not remember the exact details, but I think the main problem was that the instance of the modal has always `display:none`.

1. Make sure that you are using the `ui-bootstrap` with templates (`ui-bootstrap-tpls.js`) --  as there is the effect of graying-out you probably do.
2. In `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` go to the `modal` template at the very bottom (you can find it by: "template/modal/window.html") and add there `style="display:block". If it will not help try to match css classes of the template against your`bootstrap.css`.

I personally used some custom version of `bootstrap3`, and now have got these as template:

```
angular.module("template/modal/backdrop.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/modal/backdrop.html",
    "<div class=\"modal-backdrop fade\" ng-class=\"{in: animate}\" ng-style=\"{'z-index': 1040 + index*10}\" ng-click=\"close($event)\"></div>");
}]);

angular.module("template/modal/window.html", []).run(["$templateCache", function($templateCache) {
  $templateCache.put("template/modal/window.html",
    "<div class=\"modal fade {{ windowClass }}\" ng-class=\"{in: animate}\" style='display:block;z-index:1050'  ng-transclude></div>");
}]);
```

**EDIT** You can easily remove from your `bootstrap.css` all styles in class `modal` (and its sub-classes) where `display` is set to `none` -- `bootstrap` just hides the DOM element, whereas `ui-bootstrap` removes it completely.

Comment: I can see when I inspect the DOM that the display is none.  When I manually delete the display element the text appears in the background.  I tried to change the template/modal/window.html to match what you have here, but that did not change the display.

Comment: @Steve so you have to change your `css` as well... (I do not remember what I did exactly -- but at least you now know what is wrong)

Comment: @Steve what version of bootstrap do you use? (btw. I edited my answer)

Comment: Thank you for helping me.  The bootstrap.css is 3.0.2 and the bootstrap.tpls.js is .0.7.0.  I've edited both the .js and .css and now when the modal opens it takes up the whole screen and is transparent, blending with what is behind it.  I published my test site, if you want to click the privacy policy and see the problem.  http://stevesdevbox.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: @Steve looked at it. Try to improve the structure of your template like that: 
`<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
           ...`

Comment: artur thanks that did it for me.. basically I had a `<div class="modal">` wrapping the html structure you commented. Removing that .modal wrapper cleared it up.

Comment: Thanks. removed ui bootstrap and added ui bootstrap tpls.js.

Comment: @artur-grzesiak - well explained! it helped me. Thanks!

Comment: Had same problem. My problem was missing "ui-bootstrap-tpls.js" (point1). Problem solved. Thanks !

Answer (score 18):

This is a incompatibility with ui.bootstrap and bootstrap 3.0.

You only need to put in your css:

```
.modal {
display: block;
}
```

You can see this post for more detail: [AngularJs with UI-Bootstrap: Fix broken dialog boxes](http://blog.corveloper.com/2013/08/angularjs-with-ui-bootstrap-fix-dialog-boxes/).

Answer (score 18):

I had the exact same issue. What I did to fix it was to change what i had in my template.html, the .html provided with the `templateUrl` property in the open-function.

I had the full modal-markup there:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">And here some modal markup</div></div></div>
```

When I removed the first three divs and only had `And here some modal markup` left in the template.html it worked fine!

Comment: For me, I just had to remove the first div (the modal fade) and I kept modal-dialog and modal-content, and then it worked for me.

Answer (score 8):

The problem for me (developing with visual studio using bootstrap 4) was that the bootstrap class `.fade:not(.show)` defines `opacity: 0`. Using code inspector to disable this class, I could see that the modal would show.

However, in order to avoid modifying vendor files (namely, the `bootstrap.css` file), I simply extended the function that calls the modal to add the 'show' class to the modal page. In your example, this would be as follows:

```
$scope.showPrivacy = function() {
    $modal.open({
        templateUrl: '/Privacy',
        windowClass: 'show',
        controller: 'PrivacyInstanceController'
    });
    return false;
};
```

Normally, adding the show class to the entire window would mean that the modal is displayed continuously. This is not an issue when pages are loaded dynamically because the entire element with the `.show` class is removed when the user clicks away from the modal, irrespective of the existence of this class.

Comment: Why is this not the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

For some weird reason the modal's backdrop height isn't set to fill the window, to fix this in `ui-bootstrap-tpls.js` i went to the `template/modal/backdrop.html` line at the bottom and added the following to the style options `'width':'100%', 'height':'100%'`

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded to bootstrap v3.3.4 and now it works for me.

- Angularjs v1.3.12
- ui-bootstrap-0.12.0
- ui.bootstrap.tpls-0.12.0

Answer (score 0):

In my case the issue was that bower was installing bootstrap 4 and the ui-modal supports 3.3.7 so you need to check the version of bootstrap on bower_components