# Inserting modalInstance service in Angular UI Bootstrap

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, user-interface, controller

I am making a modal box using Angular bootstrap, I follow the following posts and its plunker example

[AngularJS Modal not showing up when templateUrl changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944900/angularjs-modal-not-showing-up-when-templateurl-changes)

Plunker example

http://plnkr.co/edit/p9qsqgMVOvT4yDmI7C0j?p=preview

And below is my code (controller)

```
.controller('apProfileDetailCtrl' , function($scope, $detailedProfileInstance , ap, newProfiles){
        $scope.hostname = ap.hostname;
        $scope.ip = ap.ipaddr;
    })
    .controller('apConfCtrl', function($scope, $q, serverProcess, printDialog, valueFactory, configLogic, $modal){
        $scope.showDetailAPInfo = function(ap, size){
            var detailedProfileInstance = $modal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'templates/profile_detail_list.html',
                    controller: 'apProfileDetailCtrl',
                    scope: $scope,
                    size: size,
                    resolve:{
                        ap:function(){
                            return ap;
                        },
                        newProfiles: function(){
                            return $scope.newTagsData;
                        },
                    }
                });
        };
```

(Markup)

```
<div class="panel-heading" style="padding:4px;">
                       <h3 class="panel-title">{{ ap.hostname }} (IP: {{ ap.ipaddr }})
                            <span style="float:right;" 
                                class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign" 
                                ng-click="showDetailAPInfo(ap,'lg')"
                                tooltip="{{ proLang.tooltip.currentAPInfo }}" 
                            ></span>
```

The above code brings me the following error
[image]

But when I remove the "$detailedProfileInstance" from the apProfileDetailCtrl controller, everything works as expected, I wonder when should I inject the service in the controller?

My thinking is, in the $modal service, the modal instance already defines the controller, therefore injecting the modal service is not allowed. Am I right?

Appreciate for any help and clarification

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code After the apProfileDetailCtrl.It works for me.

```
apProfileDetailCtrl.$inject = ['$scope', '$detailedProfileInstance'];
```

or just use

```
.controller('apProfileDetailCtrl',['$detailedProfileInstance','$scope' , function($scope, $detailedProfileInstance , ap, newProfiles){
        $scope.hostname = ap.hostname;
        $scope.ip = ap.ipaddr;
    }])
```

Comment: I have try method 2, which appears as the same result as I mentioned (Unknown provider)

Comment: Although I get what I want when omitting the injection of detailedProfileInstance, but I can't refer to the modal when in the controller apProfileDetailCtrl

Answer (score 0):

In the modal controller, looks like you believe that the modal instance must be injected just as you instantiated in your main controller (with the same name), which is wrong, instead if that, inject $modalInstance, that's the name of the provider, it doesn't matter how you called the variable which holds the modal object in your main controller, $modalInstance its the name of the provider you are missing

Comment: The reason why I inject the modal instance is that I see this option description in angular bootstrap ui "controller - a controller for a modal instance - it can initialize scope used by modal. Accepts the "controller-as" syntax in the form 'SomeCtrl as myctrl'; can be injected with $modalInstance" [http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Comment: You are not using controller-as, controller-as works for the view, not the controller itself, injecting $detailedProfileInstance means nothing to the modal controller, $modalInstance have close() and dismiss(), which are used to respond to your modal instance in your main controller (detailedProfileInstance)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figure out why I can't inject, my silly mistake for not carefully check the option api, according to the option description

> modal. Accepts the "controller-as" syntax in the form 'SomeCtrl as
>   myctrl'; can be injected with $modalInstance

So, I try to change the controller as follow

```
controller('apProfileDetailCtrl' , function($scope, $modalInstance , ap, newProfiles){
        $scope.hostname = ap.hostname;
        $scope.ip = ap.ipaddr;
    })
```

And problem solved, the injection is perfectly done!