# AngularJS bootstrap.ui modal not showing right

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to display a modal dialog using AngularJS bootstrap.ui.When I do a $modal.open(...) appears on the screen line.Before I have problem screen grays out ([AngularJS bootstrap.ui modal not showing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20255347/angularjs-bootstrap-ui-modal-not-showing),I) solved this problem, I added a new bootstrap css
I cannot figure out why I don't see any modal screen.
I am using Visual Studio 2013, MVC 5, AngularJS 1..2.
I am trying to follow this tutorial: http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/;
I am getting no error reported from the Javascript console. My app is defined as follows:

```
 var app = angular.module("app", ["ngGrid", "ui.bootstrap"]);
    app.controller("CtrlController", function ($scope, $http, $log, $modal) {
 $scope.on = function () {
           ....
            var modalInstance=  $modal.open(
                {
                    templateUrl: 'http://localhost:58652/Home/TestView',
                    controller: "CtrlController",

                }
            );

        }
```

And my markup is:

```
<div ng-click="on()" class="gridStyle" ng-grid="gridOptions">
</div>
<button ng-click="on()" type=button class="btn">Добавить</button>
```

My TestView:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="TestView">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">I'm a modal!</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in items">
                <a ng-click="selected.item = item">{{ item }}</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        Selected: <b>{{ selected.item }}</b>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="ok()">OK</button>
        <button class="btn btn-warning" ng-click="cancel()">Cancel</button>
    </div>
</script>
```

Another question: why take html-content
put in

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="TestView">
```

Answer (score 0):

If You use `<script type="text/ng-template" id="TestView"></script>` id should be `TestView.html` (good practice)

Then if You use `text/ng-template` `templateUrl` should be equal to `id`.

In your case `templateUrl: 'TestView'`

Comment: I tried this thing ,I have problem Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) May be because I do not angularjs rouiting?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview look here. ng-template should be inside your controller. Did you remove `http://localhost:58652/Home/` from `templateUrl`?